# How to retrieve contact number using a projection via an Uri with LOOKUP_KEY?

Tags: android, uri, lookup

I'm trying to use the following code to get either the contact name and its phone number:

```
String id = readFile("contactlookupkey");
Uri uri = Uri.parse (ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI + "/" + id);

  String[] projection = new String[] {
    Contacts._ID,
    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
  };

  Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query (
    uri,
    projection,
    null,
    null,
    null);

  if (!cursor.moveToNext()) // move to first (and only) row.
    throw new IllegalStateException ("contact no longer exists for key");
  String name = cursor.getString(1);
  String phone=cursor.getString(2);
  cursor.close();
```

But I'm getting an Illegal argument exception when executing the query, due to         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER.

Problem is I don't see any other way to get the phone number while still using the URI+looupkey.

What could be done to obtain the phone number?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct URI?

Try switching:

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI
```

to

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
```